# why box 2 not spanning 2 rows? instead it only make a empty space! i need that box span to 2 rows

Tags: html, css

I am new to CSS grid but I am having issues with the 'grid-row' not working; my 'movement' div does not seem to span from where I set the row from and does not go all the way down.

```css
.app {
  margin: 4rem;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 4fr 3fr;
  grid-template-rows: auto repeat(3, 10vh) auto;
  column-gap: 1rem;
  row-gap: 2rem;
}

.box {
  height: 10vh;
  background-color: rgba(255, 166, 0, 0.637);
}

.balance {
  grid-column: 1 / 3;
}

.movement {
  grid-row: 2 / 4;
}
```

```html
<div class="app">
  <div class="box balance">1</div>
  <div class="box movement">2</div>
  <div class="box summary">3</div>
  <div class="box function1">4</div>
  <div class="box function2">5</div>
  <div class="box function3">6</div>
</div>
```

[this is the output I'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QO2gb.png):

[image]

Comment: If you want to keep you `.box` height 10vh then add `height: 100%` to the `.movement` class so it takes up all of the space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because of the height property for `box` class.

```
.box {
  height: 10vh;
  background-color: rgba(255, 166, 0, 0.637);
}
```

```css
.app {
  margin: 4rem;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 4fr 3fr;
  grid-template-rows: auto repeat(3, 10vh) auto;
  column-gap: 1rem;
  row-gap: 2rem;
}

.box {
  /* height: 10vh; */
  background-color: rgba(255, 166, 0, 0.637);
}

.balance {
  grid-column: 1 / 3;
}

.movement {
  grid-row: 2 / 4;
}
```

```html
<div class="app">
  <div class="box balance">1</div>
  <div class="box movement">2</div>
  <div class="box summary">3</div>
  <div class="box function1">4</div>
  <div class="box function2">5</div>
  <div class="box function3">6</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's probably worth pointing out that the `height` property isn't necessary anyway, since `grid-template-rows` on the parent element has already handled the row-sizing.